# Display images in the list in HTML

Tags: html, mysql, django

I want to display as a list all of my medicines. I take the values from mysql database. But I cannot display images.

I get meaningless output like b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01...  instead of images.

Here is my code. How can I fixed it?

**models.py**

```
class Medicine(models.Model):

    #user = models.TextField(User)

    medicine_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    medicine_info = RichTextField(verbose_name="notes")
    medicine_code = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    medicine_price = models.IntegerField()
    medicine_stock = models.IntegerField()
    medicine_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

    def get_image(self):
        if self.medicine_image and hasattr(self.img_photo, 'url'):
            return self.medicine_image.url
        else:
            return

    def __str__(self):
        return self.medicine_name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['medicine_name']
```

**views.py**

```
def list_item(request):
    medicines = Medicine.objects.filter()
    return render(request, 'medicine_list.html', {'medicines': medicines})
```

**medicine_list.html**

```
  <table class='table'>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Info</th>
            <th>Barcode</th>
            <th>Stock</th>
            <th>Image</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      {% for medicine in medicines %}
          <tr>
            <td>{{medicine.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ medicine.medicine_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ medicine.medicine_info }}</td>
            <td>{{ medicine.medicine_code }}</td>
            <td>{{ medicine.medicine_price }}</td>
            <td>{{ medicine.medicine_image }}</td>
          </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

Comment: Use `<td><img src="{{ medicine.medicine_image.url }}"></td>`

Comment: I try it but now it shows nothing @pandafy

Comment: what does the value of medicine_image in the database look like?

Comment: Why didn't you used `medicine.get_image` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `get_image` function you check if `self.img_photo` has a certain attribute, but the problem is that `self.img_photo` doesn't exist, so the else statement runs and returns nothing.

Your function should look like the following:

```
def get_image(self):
        if self.medicine_image and hasattr(self.medicine_image, 'url'):
            return self.medicine_image.url
        else:
            # return whatever you want here
```

I also recommend specifying the `upload_to` value for your image like so:

```
medicine_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', null=True, blank=True)
```

Note that 'images' can be whatever you want.

Hope this helps!